# How exactly would my alert controller action append text to a label?

Tags: ios, swift3, append, label, uialertaction

Basically, i have an alert controller set up so that when i click a button in the view controller, an alert controller pops up and i can type words into a textfield, click an "OK" button.

Reference image

[image: alert sample]
<sub>(source: [ashfurrow.com](https://ashfurrow.com/img/import/blog/uialertviewcontroller-example/9EA0E4E86AB54891A9A27BC24D1C8889.png))</sub>

and it inserts that text into a label in the view controller. Ive extended this ability so that i can have preset keywords (like "Good," "Likely" and "Almost") that i can select from in the alert controller to speed up the typing process, as these words are typed a lot in my app. which is shown in the below image

[image: Sample].

I was wondering if you could also add those key words that I've selected to whatever is in the label? Every time i try to click a preset keyword to add to the label, it erases whatever was already in the label.

Specifically, whatever text that is already in my label, can i select a preset keyword to append to whats in the label?

This is what i have so far, for the second image:

```
//Editable Text Box with Preset Keywords

@IBOutlet weak var UselessLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func UselessTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Useless Button Tapped")
    openUselessAlert()

}

func openUselessAlert() {
    
    //Create Alert Controller
    let alert9 = UIAlertController (title: "Uselss:", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    
    //preset keyword as button in alert controller
    let bt1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Good", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.UselessLabel.text = "Good"}
    
    alert9.addAction(bt1)
    
    //preset keyword as button in alert controller
    let bt2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Likely", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.UselessLabel.text = "Likely"}
    
    alert9.addAction(bt2)
    
    //preset keyword as button in alert controller
    let bt3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Almost", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.UselessLabel.text = "Almost"}
    
    alert9.addAction(bt3)
    
    //Create Cancel Action
    let cancel9 = UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
    
    alert9.addAction(cancel9)

    
    //Create OK Action
    let ok9 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in print("OK")
        let textfield = alert9.textFields?[0]
        print(textfield?.text!)
        self.UselessLabel.text = textfield?.text!
    }
    
    alert9.addAction(ok9)
    
    //Add Text Field
    alert9.addTextField { (textfield: UITextField) in
    textfield.text = self.UselessLabel.text           

    textfield.placeholder = "Useless"
    }
    
    //Present Alert Controller
    self.present(alert9, animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

Please help! How exactly would you do this in swift 3?

Comment: You can use this `self.UselessLabel.text = self.UselessLabel.text + action.title`?

Comment: do you want to add the text to the label or to the UITextField?

Comment: i would rather add it to the textfield, but I've been told you can't do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the action text to a UILabel you can use

```
 let bt3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Almost", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.UselessLabel.text = self.UselessLabel.text + action.title}
```

and if you want to add to UITextField in the AlertView then you must do something like this

```
let bt3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Almost", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in if(alert9.textFields.count > 0)
            {
                alert9.textFields[0].text = alert9.textFields[0].text + action.title
            }
          }
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: your ui textfield code says my: "instance member 'textFields' cannot be use on type 'AlertController'"

Comment: is there a way to put it into the label and then instantly bring up the alert controller again (with the text in the textfield)?

Comment: @DanielG did my answer solve your problem finally?, you need to use `alert9` instead of `alertController` my answer was edited

Comment: i had to correct some errors to make it build, but nothing happens when i click the almost button:

     let bt3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Almost", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
            (action) in if((alert9.textFields?.count)! > 0)
            {
                alert9.textFields?[0].text = (alert9.textFields?[0].text)! +     action.title!
            }
        }

Comment: @DanielG I will test and I will update my final answer, in 1hr or two

Comment: @DanielG I think that maybe the best solution for this is create your own viewController to present as dialog with all your requeriments, because once you click on an action dialog dismiss automatically

Comment: im not sure what you mean by this

Comment: @DanielG I mean, once you touch any dialog button with this implementation the dialog is closed, so if you use your own viewController and setup your buttons and the wanted behavior and present over current context, can work for you, sorry for my english